# Code coverage of dev code via QA automation repo

Tags: code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin, test-coverage, jacoco-plugin

I am very new to Jacoco. Everywhere I see how to configure Jacoco where the main class and test class exist in same repo. But practically, I have an automation repo in github and then I have 4 different service repos. I want to know when I run my automation script, how much code coverage from all these four repos is done. Is that possible? If yes then how?

Please note, all the projects (dev/automation) are in Java and gradle project.
We use Github for CI/CD.